# JavaScript -- How many items start with a certain letter?

Tags: javascript

I have the answer, sort of.  But at the end, I just want it to say, "There are two names that start with the letter B"  Not what I get now.

```
var count = 0
a = ["Bill", "Julia", "Coral", "Wendy", "Bob"];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].startsWith("B")) {
    count++;
    }
    console.log("B" + " is at the beginning of " + count + " names");
    }
```

Comment: And what is your question? your console log is inside the `for` loop....

Comment: Indenting code (correctly) is the beginning of code-wisdom.

Comment: When it runs.  I just want it to output "B is at the beginning of 2 names."    Right now it says:                                                                                         B is at the beginning of 1 names
B is at the beginning of 2 names                                                                          Indenting code?  I am a total newbie and this hasn't been covered AT ALL!!!!  I'll hae to read up on it.

Comment: I got it!!!  Looks like it matters where the {} are -- I was just adding them on the end if I didn't have enough -- as in they didn't match the number of {, I was adding a } at the end.. Extreme rookie mistake.  Now I know!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things not right. First, there is a `,` missing after declaring the variable count. And last, you have the `console.log()` statement inside of the loop. So it gets called a few more times then you desired. You have to put it underneath the loop.

This code should work for you:

```
var count = 0,
    a = ["Bill", "Julia", "Coral", "Wendy", "Bob"];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].startsWith("B")) {
        count++;
    }
}

console.log("B" + " is at the beginning of " + count + " names");
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what is wrong with this answer? (+1)

Comment: Yep.  it works!  Awesome!  I've been putting the console.log inside everything, I didn't know it could stand alone like that. Your explanation makes total sense.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [RegExp](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/regexp):

```js
const names = ["Bill", "Julia", "Coral", "Wendy", "Bob"];

let startsWith = (names,letter) => { 
  return names.filter(name => {
    let pattern = new RegExp('^'+letter);
    return name.match(pattern);
  });
};

console.log( 
  'There are ' + startsWith(names,"B").length + ' names that start with "B"',
  startsWith(names,"B")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var count = 0,a = ["Bill", "Julia", "Coral", "Wendy", "Bob"];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        //Easy way is to grab the first letter 
        if (a[i].substring(0)[0].match(/B/ig)) {
            count=count+1;
            console.log(a[i].substring(0)[0]+" is at the beginning of "+a[i]);
        }

    }


    //TYPICALLY NOT IN THE LOOP
    //AND NOW HERE YOU HAVE ALL THAAT MATCHED....
    if(count>0){
        //some words start with the letter B
        //remeber to reset it @ last you u r gonna reuse it!
    }else{
        //nothing matched...
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have added. I have to use the .startsWith

Comment: U r welcome.   But of ovcos u can make it whatever u want it to be perhaps it is highly customlisable.